# Problem solved?

Tags: discussion

On Meta, the CTO has posted [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps).  I'm pleased with it, I think it's genuine and a much more appropriate response than what was put out originally.  But I don't understand what this means for our mods.

Will Monica come back?  Will mods "un-resign"?  Are we going back to normal?

Comment: SE has not yet contacted me.  I suspect other things depend on that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this whole mess is far from over.

Comment: Right now, that post is just words on a page. I'll accept that the problem is fixed when and *only* when Monica says it is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my uninformed opinion the issue goes as follows:

- SE builds a platform on which a community develops with a fair degree of independence.
- SE decides that a community representative is no longer to their taste, and they summarily dismiss her
- A mild uproar ensues
- CTO writes I am sorry to placate the uproar

  and we are back to square one, with nearly no change.

They wanted to show that they are the sole rulers of these lands and they have done so very clearly. The next time they decide that someone else, or some other topic, or some content, is not to their liking, they still retain the same power and most-likely the same mindset to do as they please. Maybe they will be more subtle, if the negative publicity was ever amongst their concerns, or less subtle if they will think that any publicity, positive or negative, is still publicity.

To my understanding there is no plan to separate the powers of SE the company from SE the community. There is no plan to prevent future abuses. There is no plan to give the community the power to undo these abuses.

We are millions, that is true, but together we do not hold one millionth of the executive power of the last of SE's staff who lurks around these forums with a watchful eye. That is why the issue still stands.

Comment: My two cents: It took well over a week for this "apology" to materialise. Since then, we hear that Monica has not been contacted, nor have we had any explanation from TPTB as to their reasoning for their behaviour, in fact they have tried to suggest that they felt there was some kind of imminent danger in having Monica as a moderator? What danger? Explain yourselves please. Honestly, a weeks late apology that doesn't elucidate a damn thing is not worth much to me.

Comment: yeah, they're just bs'ing us; no idea why so many people are accepting the "apology"...